# Is there any way retrieve data from MsSQL db using PHP but not the built-in PHP MsSQL-library?

Tags: php, sql-server, shared-hosting

Is there any way to retrieve data from an mssql database using php, but not using the mssql librayr from php?

In advance I would like to state that my experience with php is no more than 10 months.

I need to retrieve some information from an mssql database, using php. 
When I attempt to run the code underneath I get the following error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()
```

I have tracked the source of this error, and found that mssql is not configured in php. I furthermore suspect that I do not have the liberty to change these configurations on my server as I work on a shared web server.

Is there any way to work around this, to get the data I need?

For your information my code is:

```
$link = mssql_connect($host,$username,$password);
mssql_select_db($dbname, $link);
$query= "SELECT * FROM tbl_Update";
$riskupdates = mssql_query($query);
```

And my php config:

[image]

Comment: I take it that the host is a remote machine? If the server you are running on does not have the library installed then you will need to run it on another server. This is not as hard as it sounds since installing PHP and apache/IIS on your own machine is relatively straight forward. You then need to install the mssql extension and run your code from localhost/my_file.php.

Comment: The server is a standard web hotel, and the application has to serve a global client market temporarily. We do not have an extra server/machine to spare.

Comment: After talking to the host service provider I solved the problem, getting the MSSQL configured in PHP.

Comment: I was going to say that the only other alternative would be to export it into a database that the server can handle, probably MySQL.